# Tripod mount missing!

Tags: telescope

I have received a new Celestron Powerseeker 127 (a 5' short Newtonian), however it came without a tripod mount.

Ideas or suggestions on how to procure the right mount our a suitable alternative would be most welcome.

I am looking for sourcing tips rather than advice on how to choose a tripod.

Comment: Did you buy it yourself from a dealer, was it given as a gift, etc? (For a new scope I would always recommend getting the right part from the dealer, as you wouldn't want to invalidate a warranty by fitting an equivalent part.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I look for in an astronomy tripod?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/7917/what-should-i-look-for-in-an-astronomy-tripod)

Comment: @sir Not really asking for technical advice on how to choose a good tripod as much as wondering where do I find the part? :)

Comment: @andy it was a gift... no seller to go back to.

Comment: If you've been given the tube (the optical tube assembly) and need a tripod or mount, you could always search for the current Celestron catalog and see if it's possible to buy the bits you need. Otherwise, I'd suggest Amateur Telescope Making (ATM) - build a simple but solid Dobsonian mount out of wood... (lots of design ideas online.) (Also - the answer James has just posted mentions a few of the common mounts well known to the astronomical community which you could search for.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A high end photographic tripod would probably work but it will be difficult to make small tracking adjustments. So a proper astronomical mount would be much better.

An EQ2 mount would just about manage a scope of that size however an EQ3-2 would be a lot more stable and have the advantage that you can either get a goto version initially or upgrade at a later date.

If you are on a tighter budget and/or don't want an equatorial mount then something like a Celestron Heavy Duty Alt/Az Tripod or Skywatcher AZ3 Alt Az Mount would be suitable.

All of the mounts mentioned are available from numerous online retailers but shop around as prices can vary.

Comment: There are a lot of Celestron go-to AZ mounts on eBay presently, but I am not sure how or if those could be mated to this optical tube.

Comment: 0xF2 - what mounting hardware does it have - in particular do you have the rings that go round the tube, which are needed to attach the scope to most types of mount.

Comment: @DrChuck: thankfully it did come with the rings that grip the tube, and a mounting plate joining the two that has screw holes.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "vixen/synta mounts" you should find lots of compatible mounts and tripods.  There is a huge range of prices and level of features. Check out what the specifications say about their load capacity, relative to the weight of your scope.